# How to pass parameters while creating consul client agent inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, consul, consul-template

I'm running Consul client agent inside a Docker container.
I have created a docker-compose file as below:

```
agent:
   hostname: sample.host.com
   container_name: consul_agent
   image: privatedockerregistry/consul-agent:0.6.4
   restart: always
   environment:
     - SERVICE_IGNORE=always
   ports:
     - 8300:8300
     - 8301:8301
     - 8301:8301/udp
     - 8302:8302
     - 8302:8302/udp
     - 8400:8400
   command: --join 11.201.150.108 --join 11.201.342.203 -dc dc_consul -advertise 11.201.343.213
```

**Please let me know how can i pass the below options in the docker-compose:**

```
  "enable_syslog": true,
  "disable_update_check": true,
  "domain": "consul.domain.com",


  "ports": {
    "dns": 8600,
    "rpc": 8400,
    "serf_lan": 8301,
    "serf_wan": 8302,
    "server": 8300,
    "https": -1,
    "http": 8700
  },
  "datacenter": "consul_dc",
  "acl_datacenter": "consul_dc",
  "acl_default_policy": "deny",
  "acl_master_token": "04asdsec-327d-rd4f-b277-d6a20b80f683"
```

Answer (score 0):

Map them to environment variables?

```
environment:
    -PORTS_DNS=8600
    -PORTS_RPC=8400
```

Reconstruct them on the other side?

If you don't want to do that then perhaps you need to add a configuration server like zookeeper or spring cloud config server: https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/app-configuration-management-with-config-servers-in-cloud-foundry

Comment: I have mapped them to environment variables. But, when the i `cat` the config.json file within the docker container, I don't see `  "ports" : {
 
    "dns" : 8600,
    "http" : 8500,
    "https" : -1,
    "rpc" : 8400,
    "serf_lan" : 8301,
    "serf_wan" : 8302,
    "server" : 8300

  } `